# Serving Ads in Android App -

Tags: android, ads

I am trying to better understand various platforms to serve ads in my Android application. 
It is a free application and is a Location based reminder - has been localized into 7 languages. It is a native Android App.  It is not yet on the market place. I want to stick in the Ads support before I publish it. The Application requires Internet access even if I do not use serve the Ads.

I started assuming I can use AdSense, but then my application has been rejected. I do not have website or a blog with high traffic. What options do I have? I looked at other Google Ads Platform - AdMob/AdWhirl and DoubleClick. And then there are those non-Google Platforms such as Smatoo and Mojiva.

These various platforms and different approaches, suggest it is a crowded field and confusing too for a newcomer. Can the readers please provide their insights and suggestions based on their experience? What options do I have?
Thank you

Comment: Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6262918/741249) for a list of the available advertising networks. There are links to several reviews as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With my apps I have done decent with both [AdMob](http://www.admob.com) and [Mobclix](http://www.mobclix.com). Currently I use a hybrid of Mobclix as the Primary and failing over to Admob when Mobclix does not return an ad. The good thing about Mobclix is that it is a mediator between 15-20 different ad companies including Smatoo, Mojiva, etc. So you don't have to individually register to each one.

Comment: Thank you - I will do something similar

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check out Appmobi, Leadbolt and Burstly. Leadbolt has some high performance ad types that do way better than banners if placed well.

Answer (score 0):

We have done well with Mocean mobile managing yield and perfromance for inventory, and mojiva selling it.

Hope that helps.